# Cannot using SQLAdapter of Worklight in WP8.1 device

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using SQLAdapter in worklight. 
I invoke procedure successfully in worklight console and WP8 emulator. But when I deloy app to my WP8.1 device

```
<driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://118.xx.xx.xx:3306/petrodb</url>
            <user>petro</user>
            <password>123@abc</password> 

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(loginData,{
    onSuccess : loginSuccess,
    onFailure : loginFailure
});
```

worklight console and elulator -> go to loginSuccess function

my wp8.1 device -> goto loginFailure function

Anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks,

Edit: 
error log :

> Error:"[http: //169. 254.80.80:10080/petro/apps/services/api/Xangdau/windowsphone8/query] Host is not responsive."

169.254.80.80:10080 is server host of worklight?

Edit2:
-  When I run this app on Emulator and Device, it call go 169.254.80.80:10080 of worklight. When I close eclipse, my app can't invoke procedure on Emulator,too. I think the reason is that my device cannot find where is 169.254.80.80.

Comment: 1) Make sure the device is connected to the same network as the worklight server. 2) provide logs when running on the device. I'm not sure if you will see them in the output view in Visual Studio when running in a device - check.

Comment: Is your database firewalled to prevent connections from the outside world?

Comment: About the IP address - only you can know that obvioulsy... the host is your machine's IP address... Again, verify the device and the computer connect to the same network.

Comment: @Shaw : no, I turned off firewall, and I can connect it from worklight console and wp8 emulator

Comment: @IdanAdar : 118.xx.xx.xx:3306 is my remote server. It works perfectly. My PC (run wp8 emulator) and My WP8 device connect to the same WIFI. But only the emulator can get data.

Comment: Thai, please learn how to use Worklight! If you close Eclise, you close your SERVER, and thus of course adapter procedures will fail

Comment: @IdanAdar :  Eclipse only run on my PC, so where do my device connect to invoke procedure ?. I think wl server was deploy to device ?

Comment: During development, the Worklight server IS eclipse. The Worklight studio plugin contains an embedded Worklight server. Thus, closing eclipse closes the server. During production, you install Worklight server in an application server. For this, you must purchase a Worklight license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check whether you can able to connect to Worklight server from Device.

- Open the worklight server console from your device default browser by entering `http://serveripaddress:port/contextroot/console`. If you cant able to access the URL then you have to connect to device to the server network

You will get error like `Host is not responsive` when your worklight server is not reachable from your device.

Comment: I tried this on my emulator, it display worklight console. But on my device, it's not

Comment: So your mobile device is not connected to same network. Tel me how you are connecting mobile to your server? Any wifi?

Comment: My PC (run wp8 emulator) and My WP8 device connect to the same WIFI. But only the emulator can get data and can connect to http://serveripaddress:port/contextroot/console

Comment: Try to connect to some other server or any other hosted sites from your device ( which is accessible from your PC). if you cant connect means there is a problem with your mobile Wifi.

Also just double check the URL before entering in device. Sometimes browser will append `www`